# Typescript function not waiting for the waitForExist() and printing the next line

Tags: javascript, typescript, webdriver.io, reactjs, jestjs

I'm using webdriverIO with typescript and jest to automate react application. 
I have a simple test to check how long it takes for a particular element to display on the screen. There's a process which runs on clicking a button and once the process is completed, a popup is displayed on the screen.

I'm printing time before I wait for the element and then printing it after. Below is the code:

```
 $("//button[@testid='btn-submit']").click();
    const time1 = Date.now();
    console.log("Time started --- " + time1);
    $(".messagedialog").waitForExist(600000);
    const time2 = Date.now();
    console.log("Time Ended --- " + time2);
    $("//span[text()='View Result']").click();
```

When it runs, it prints the line "Time Ended --" right after "Time Started -- ", even though the application is still waiting for the message dialog. I'm running webdriverIO in the sync mode using @wdio/sync.

Why the "Time Ended" line is getting printed even though previous statement ".waitForExist()" has not returned true yet?

Comment: It's working correctly for me, make sure that .messagedialog is not present in the DOM because waitforexit check only for the presence and not visibility.

Comment: Thanks! That was it.. there was another dialog on the screen with the same class name, causing this issue.

Comment: please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign near to the answer

Answer (score 2):

WaitForExit() checks only for the presence of and not the visibility. You could use `$(selector).waitForDisplayed` instead. And also ensure there is no other element with the same selector.